# write two items seperated by / in html

Tags: html, css

I want to write these two addresses in my heading, I tried this code but "/" doesn't place in the same line. could anyone help me fix it?

```
<header>
    <nav class="header">
        <h1>CRIS</h1>
        <p class="light_grey">Art direction design</p>
        <div class="address">
            <address>Call me (+706)098-0751</address>
            <p>/</p>
            <address>cris@gmail.com</address>
        </div>

        <p>Menu</p>
    </nav>
</header>
```

and this is css code :

```
.header {
    justify-content: space-around;
    display: flex;
    }

.address {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-around;
   }
```

[image: the sample of the output]

Comment: Have you tried using <span>/<span>?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `align-items: center` to it:

```css
.address {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="address">
    <address>Call me (+706)098-0751</address>
    <p>/</p>
    <address>cris@gmail.com</address>
</div>
```

Because by default, [`<p>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p) tag has some vertical margins applied it, you could also set `.address p { margin: 0; }` to get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions to your problem. For example, here are two of the many:

This is `@Hao Wu` answer, using `align-items: center`. <--- Better use this solution.

This is to use `margin` rules, like this:

```
.address address, 
.address p { 
   margin-top: auto; 
   margin-bottom: auto; 
}
```